# Windows CLI equivalent to "sort -u"

Tags: windows, sorting, unique, command-line-interface

I need an equivalent way in a Windows CLI to do what I would be able to in Linux/UNIX in piping through to show unique values.

I don't think there is a command as such, from what I can gather, so is there another way to do this?

What I have to achieve is to list files from multiple directories (whether they exist or not, which I currently do using `dir`).  The way that the script (for the requesting application) works uses multiple sources to construct a directory list and subsequently the command depending on whether the platform is Windows or UNIX but the danger here is that there is a possibility of duplicate directories in the list and this would skew the results at the other end.

The easiest way to deal with this is to do it at source, i.e. the original command being run.  So in Linux, the command structure is more or less:

```
find [dir] [dir] [dir] | grep file_name | sort -u
```

Doing the same in Windows is obviously more difficult given that:

- it has to be a native read only command/script string you would use from Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`)
- I can't install anything on the hosts this is run on
- I can't create temporary text files as part of the process

Answer (score 11):

1. Microsoft has added a `/unique` switch to `sort.exe` in Windows 10 but has forgotten to update its documentation. I tested this switch on Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 v1709. It was present in the latter but absent from the first two.

   So, `sort.exe /unique` is the equivalent of UNIX `sort -u`.
2. PowerShell already has a `Sort-Object` cmdlet that supports a `-Unique` switch. Better still, by default, PowerShell defines the alias `sort` for `Sort-Object` so, `| sort -unique` is pretty much all you need.

Comment: Microsoft still hasn't documented `sort.exe`'s `/unique` switch in Windows 11, but it continues to work.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
SET "line="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('sort q22351713.txt') DO (
 IF "!line!" neq "%%a" ECHO(%%a
 set "line=%%a"
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q22351713.txt` for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

Not bullet-proof

Always better to explain what the original does rather than assume it's obvious.

Comment: I can't create any text file on the host. This is going to be run on multiple endpoints from a central discovery tool, so the command would have to be read only and as in the other suggestion, using native (non-powershell) commands! Oh and yes, tell me about it! ;)

Comment: Added some detail to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty batch is dirty...

```
%COMSPEC% /d /v:on /c "(SET LASTLINE=) & (FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %L IN (`DIR /b /s /-p dir1 dir2 dir3 dir3 dir2 dir1 "dir with space" ^| %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\find.exe /i "search_file_name" ^| %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\sort.exe`) DO @((IF /i NOT "{!LASTLINE!}"=="{%~L}" ECHO %~L) & SET "LASTLINE=%~L"))"
```

Let's break this down a bit...

`%COMSPEC% /d /v:on /s /c "..."` - you wanted a single command, not a batch, and we needed delayed expansion (`/v:on`), so we invoke a subshell using the known executable of the Windows Command Prompt (`%COMSPEC%`).  We don't want to run autoexec.bat (`/d`) and we want to run the command and move on, rather than leaving an interactive shell (`/c "..."`).  Quoting is a funky problem, so we try for some 'standardised' behaviour (`/s`)

`SET LASTLINE=` - empty any current content of a `LASTLINE` environment variable

`(...) & (...)` - run everything before `&` and everything after `&` regardless of the exit code of the first bit.  Use brackets as appropriate to group commands, where needed.

`` FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %L IN (`...`) DO ... `` - run the command string between backquotes (`usebackq`) and read all words (`tokens=*`) in each line of stdout (`FOR /f`) into a temporary variable `%L`.

`DIR /b /s /-p dir1 dir2 dir3 dir3 dir2 dir1 "dir with space"` - recursively (`/s`) enumerate through `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3` and `dir with space`, printing only the full path of files to stdout (`/b`).  Don't require keypresses to page the output, if that has been set (`/-p`). Note that, due to foibles of `FOR` it is up to you to *only* quote directories with special chars (e.g. space), i.e. do not quote single-word names.

`... ^| ...` - pipe the stdout of the first command to the stdin of the second.  We use `^` to escape `|` within the backquotes of `FOR`.

`%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\find.exe /i "search_file_name"` - find the string `search_file_name` in stdin.  Use a case-insensitive search (`/i`).

`%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\sort.exe` - sort stdin and write to stdout.

`DO @(...)` - we need to run two commands for each line, so we group them in brackets.  `FOR` normally prints each command before it runs it, the `@` suppresses this.

`(IF /i NOT "{!LASTLINE!}"=="{%~L}" ECHO %~L)` - if the line we are looking at `%~L` is not the same as the line we have stored `!LASTLINE!`, print the line we are looking at.  Again, use a case-insensitive comparison (`/i`).  We bookend both variables with `{}` to handle empty values, and we use delayed expansion (`!LASTLINE!` instead of `%LASTLINE%`) to expand `LASTLINE` every time it loops, not just when the `FOR` command is first seen.

`SET "LASTLINE=%~L"` - store the line we are looking at `%~L` into the variable `LASTLINE`.

If you do not have access to the inbuilt environment variables, you may not have `%SYSTEMROOT%` or `%COMSPEC%`.  Substitute these for `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` or, more appropriately, determine the correct locations for the system you are scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Download [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) utility, it is simple Linux terminal under windows.
It allow to execute any Linux command in Windows.
And you have sort -u there.